# JFrame-JDialog comunication

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame main window wich has a Register button on in.Click the register button and the JDialog windows pops out.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Reg new1=new Reg(users);
                new1.setVisible(true);
            }
```

The JDialog window has 2 buttons->Register,Cancel.Both of them must do something and close the Dialog window.

This is what I tried.
In the Reg(Dialog window)---> btnCancel:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        dialog.dispose();
                        System.out.println("Reg disposed by cancel button");
                    }
```

This closes the D window when run just the D window but I guess when executed from the main window(Button clicked) it still exists like an object in the main fraim"class" and doesn't close.What should I do ?How do I make it close ?

Comment: What do you mean, when executed from the main window - it should be executed by user action. And FWIW, an ActionListener might be more appropriate to handle JButton events.

Comment: jframe has a  button, clicking the button opens the jdialog

Comment: `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {`  Don't add mouse listeners to buttons!  Add an action listener instead and the button will respond to both mouse **and keyboard** input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way for the frame to determine how the dialog was closed

```
// Why are you using a `MouseListener` on buttons??
// User use keyboards to, use an ActionListener instead
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Reg new1=new Reg(users);
    new1.setVisible(true);
    switch (new1.getDisposeState()) {
        case Reg.OK:
            // Clicked Ok
            break;
        case Reg.CANCEL:
            // Clicked cancel or was closed by press [x]
            break;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Reg` class, you need to maintain information about the state...

```
public class Reg extends JDialog {
    public static final int OK = 0;
    public static final int CANCEL = 1;

    private int disposeState = CANCEL;

    //...

    public int getDisposeState() {
        return disposeState
    }

    public void setDisposeState(int state) {
        disposeState = state;
    }
```

Then you change the state

```
// Why are you using a `MouseListener` on buttons??
// User use keyboards to, use an ActionListener instead
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    setDisposeState(CANCEL);
    dialog.dispose();
    System.out.println("Reg disposed by cancel button");
}
```

This all assumes that your dialog is modal of course...

Now, having said all that, personally, I would make your `Reg` class a `JPanel` and add it to a `JOptionPane` instead or use a `CardLayout`

Take a look at:

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)
- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

...for more details